# Как отделить иконки, чтобы не было видимого расстояния

Tags: html, css

margin, padding не подходят, при свойстве cursor:pointer, и margin-right выделяется блок элементов, а не отдельная иконка (иконки твиттера инсты и фейсбука)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap');
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.container
{
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg
{
    background-color: #1E252B;
}
header
{
    padding-top: 31px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; 
}
.logo-bg
{
    background-color: #FF6E30;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 38px;
    width: 38px;
    position: relative;
}
.img1
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 47%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.img2
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 41%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.logo h1
{
    color: white;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.menu-item a
{
    color: #9A9D9F;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
.auth a
{
    color: #9A9D9F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
button
{
    background-color: #FF6E30;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 320ms;
}
button:hover
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
.wrapper
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.title
{
    color: white;
}
.first-title
{
    font-size: 35px;
    padding-top: 178px;
}
.first-title span
{
    color: #FF6E30;
}
.second-title
{
    color: #9A9D9F;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.form
{
    padding-top: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    background-color: #283036; 
    border: 1.5px solid #252829;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.form i
{
    color: #ADB0B2;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.form input
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 65px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
.form button
{
    padding: 15px 40px;
}
.icons
{
    margin-top: 130px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 78%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.icons i
{
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 33px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.5.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <div class="logo-bg">
                    <img class="img1" src="img/Subtractss-1.svg" alt="">
                    <img class="img2" src="img/Subtractss.svg" alt="">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <h1>antools.</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Home</a>
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Categories</a>
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">My Collections</a>
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Blog</a>
                </div>
                <div class="auth">
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Login</a>
                    <button>Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">  
                <section class="title">  
                    <div class="first-title">
                        <h1>Awesome tools for<br> Designer & Developer<span>.</span></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="second-title">
                        <p>Antool is a web collection of information on paid of<br> free Design and Development tools</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-magnify"></i>
                        <input type="search" name="search" class="input" placeholder="find more than 430+ tools" required>
                        <button type="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icons">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-facebook"></i>
                        <i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i>
                        <i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <img src="img/sd.png" alt="s">    
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда вам надо объявлять `cursor: pointer;` не в общем блоке, а на самих иконках.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap');
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.container
{
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg
{
    background-color: #1E252B;
}
header
{
    padding-top: 31px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; 
}
.logo-bg
{
    background-color: #FF6E30;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 38px;
    width: 38px;
    position: relative;
}
.img1
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 47%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.img2
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 41%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.logo h1
{
    color: white;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.menu-item a
{
    color: #9A9D9F;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
.auth a
{
    color: #9A9D9F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
button
{
    background-color: #FF6E30;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 320ms;
}
button:hover
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
.wrapper
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.title
{
    color: white;
}
.first-title
{
    font-size: 35px;
    padding-top: 178px;
}
.first-title span
{
    color: #FF6E30;
}
.second-title
{
    color: #9A9D9F;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.form
{
    padding-top: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    background-color: #283036; 
    border: 1.5px solid #252829;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.form i
{
    color: #ADB0B2;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.form input
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 65px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
.form button
{
    padding: 15px 40px;
}
.icons
{
    margin-top: 130px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 78%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.icons i
{
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 33px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.icons i:hover {
  color: #ff0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.5.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <div class="logo-bg">
                    <img class="img1" src="img/Subtractss-1.svg" alt="">
                    <img class="img2" src="img/Subtractss.svg" alt="">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <h1>antools.</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Home</a>
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Categories</a>
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">My Collections</a>
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Blog</a>
                </div>
                <div class="auth">
                    <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Login</a>
                    <button>Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">  
                <section class="title">  
                    <div class="first-title">
                        <h1>Awesome tools for<br> Designer & Developer<span>.</span></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="second-title">
                        <p>Antool is a web collection of information on paid of<br> free Design and Development tools</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-magnify"></i>
                        <input type="search" name="search" class="input" placeholder="find more than 430+ tools" required>
                        <button type="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icons">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-facebook"></i>
                        <i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i>
                        <i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <img src="img/sd.png" alt="s">    
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: благодарю))))))